# How can I use my CPanel/WHM panel to manage my R53 domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cpanel

I'm new and I recentely installed `Cpanel/WHM` into a `AWS EC2`, everything works fine, but I have a question about it.

It is possible to register an A type registry on R53 pointing to my own DNS server (`CPanel/WHM`). 
For example: 
My server is `server.com`, and there I have a DNS server that works fine and where I have multiple domains registered on it.
If I register `ns1.server.com` into R53  like `A` registry and it points to my server. Would it works globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not really need to register your nameservers with R53 if you just want your server to act as authority on that domain. You would need to go to your domain registrar and point the name server entries there to your DNS server that is running on the EC2 instance.

But you would also need a DNS entry for that name server somewhere. If you are running your app on AWS unless you need your own NS for some kind of custom setup I would just use R53. Works great and is much cheaper than using a server specifically for that purpose.